# Need help with objects moving toward the player

Tags: xna, 2d, physics

I am making a 2D game with simple "gravity": everything is just pulled toward 0,0. The speed at which they accelerate towards it is `GravityAcceleration` up to `MaxGSpeed`.

I also want the player to be able to pull these objects too. I'm using `Magnitism` and `MaxSpeed` to deal with the acceleration and speed at which the objects move towards the player.

However, it doesn't work, and I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong. The `MoveToPlayer` function is only called if the player is within 500 units of the object.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    var vectorToSun = new Vector2(0, 0) - Position;
    var distanceToCenter = vectorToSun.Length();

    vectorToSun.Normalize();
    _velocity += vectorToSun * GravityAcceleration * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    if (_velocity.Length() > MaxGSpeed)
    {
        _velocity.Normalize();
        _velocity *= MaxGSpeed;
    }

    Position += _velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    rotation += 0.003f;
}

public void MoveToPlayer(Vector2 playerPos, GameTime gameTime)
{
    var vectorToPlayer = playerPos - Position;

    vectorToPlayer.Normalize();
    _velocity += vectorToPlayer * Magnitism * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    if (_velocity.Length() > MaxSpeed)
    {
        _velocity.Normalize();
        _velocity *= MaxSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: the 'MoveToPlayer' method looks sound. Sorry to state the obvious but are you calling it? Also, put a breakpoint somewhere toward the end of it and verify 'Position' & 'Magnitism' values are as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use 'TotalSeconds'? If youre calling the function each frame, shouldnt you use the time elapsed last frame? (I dont know the exact property name, i havent used xna before)

Comment: @Aralox is definitely right!!! try some kind of `ElapsedGameTime.FrameTime`.. make sure this is (far) less than 1 (e.g. 0.01) if you're doing it on a per-frame basis. It can happen that your velocity is always "normalized" since it ought to be greater than your `MaxSpeed` threshold.

Comment: `gameTime.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds` is **correct**. Note the `ElapsedTime` in that property chain. Total seconds means get the total number of seconds in the `TimeSpan` (as opposed to Seconds, which gets the whole number of seconds). The Timespan in that case is the `ElapsedTime`, i.e. time between frames.

Comment: What do you mean `However, it doesn't work`?  Do objects not move toward the player?  Do they move too fast? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Could you add the code, where you are calling these methods?